# Ktor Exposed SELECT Type mismatch

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I'm new in ktor and exposed. When i use DSL to SELECT a data from my database IDE show an error with this message : `Type mismatch. Required: Op<Boolean> Found: Unit`

this is my code :

```
val count = User.select { User.mobile eq mobile }.limit(1).count()
```

any idea?

Comment: Don't see any obvious problems with this code line. Could you share more code in order to provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь thanks for your comment, yes i find out the problem , the type of mobile field was JsonObject instead of string.